# Unable to load the requested language file

Tags: module, language

I'm using EE 2.6.1 and the default language is Dutch. When installing a module it seems that a specific lang file should be added in the language directory. I don't know which modules add lang files.  All works fine but when I log out I get an Error when accessing the front-end site. If I'm logged in the front end doesn't show errors.

Right now I make a copy of a lang file en rename it.

Is there something I should adjust with the configuration?
Or is there a solution to bypass this when a lang file is missing?

Tnx,

Comment: I thought that it used the English language file, then loaded the specific language over the top, therefore if there's anything missing from the language specific, the English caught it. So if the file is completely missing, the English file was still used. Can you give examples of what module and what the error message is?

Comment: Hi Peter, The error was "Unable to load the requested language file: language/dutch/social_update_lang.php" This file didn't exist but was also missing in the English language dir. The module is Social Update (IntoEEtive). I had it with a few other modules as well a while back. So I don't think it's a module specific issue.  When installing a module, is a lang file added or isn't that standard protocol?

Comment: I was looking in the system language dir. That explains the missing English lang files. The English lang files in the modules do exist.